# In GMail, can I auto-forward emails between two accounts so I can view all my mail on both?

Tags: email, gmail, forwarding, email-filter

I realize this is probably a pretty uninformed question, but I'm not really sure how to search for it. My apologies if this is a duplicate or whatever. I don't use this site a lot, I'm a bit frustrated, and just want to get this done.

My college forces me to use two Gmail accounts. If I set up auto-forwarding for both accounts so I can look at all my e-mail regardless of which I'm logged into, will it cause an infinite auto-forward loop?
My college forces me to use multiple email accounts and its incredibly annoying to me.
Ideally, I'd like to be able to look at all my email from both accounts. I'm sick of having to switch between them especially since the way its set up with my college causes ridiculous glitches at times.

I already have email forwarding to one of my accounts, but I'm worried that if I try to do it for both it could cause a problem
e.g.:

*On account 1, I receive email "A"

*Receiving email on account 1 triggers auto-forward

*On account 2, I receive "fwd:A"

*Receiving email on account 2 triggers auto-forward

*On account 1, I receive email "fwd:fwd:A"

*Receiving email on account 2 triggers auto-forward

etc....
I would try it myself, but you know, I'd rather not break my email.

**[Edit 2: The rest is anxious, frustrated rambling over-explanation. Save yourself a headache; cease reading here and don't look at the struck-out text below]**

<strike>That's my main question and now I've got a headache from thinking about forwarded forwarding so I'll be quick in adding also that I just generally want to know how auto-forward treat forwarded and auto-forwarded messages. 
Anyone know?</strike>

Edit: I would create a third account or just use my main account, but the problem is there are times (frequent, too) where I have to be logged into either one for a whole slew of different reasons not even just related to email.

Comment: Basic answers are already on Google https://support.google.com/mail/answer/10957?hl=en

Comment: That was the first thing that I tried. That does not answer my specific question. I have been trying to search around and read what google has to say and all that, but I'm having trouble with that so I'm asking here in the hopes someone might be able to answer a question I'm not sure I can find an answer to. Maybe I missed it, but I'm not really seeing an answer to this. I see questions about whether a situation similar to this could occur (apparently, what I described is a "thing"), but those don't answer my specific question either.

Comment: Interesting question, maybe someone has tried it and can report if it goes into an infinite loop, I assume Google would prevent this somehow.

Comment: Yeah... it looks like not many people have done this. Maybe if I spend some time later, I can try and think of some other kind of solution like filters (probably not actually this) or something. I'm also thinking maybe I could experiment with some other unused accounts I happen to have laying around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is to use filters. Turn off google's automatic forwarding, then set up a filter rule that will forward messages with the current account's email address in the `to` field to your other email address. The forwarded messages should keep their original to: address, and thus will not trigger the forwarding filter when they reach the other account. Do the same on the other account.

Comment: Oh, thanks.
I know its been well over a month now, but I didn't see this answer for whatever reason and chose to focus on other things I was busy with.

I'm not real familiar with special email settings/functions, so I might have to look around a little, but I'm sure I'll find it pretty fast.

So, gmail has filters for that... That's nice.